# AngularJS filter nested ng-repeat based on repeated object properties

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have an array of restaurant objects and I want to list them by grouping their cities

My object is like;

```
restaurant = {
     id: 'id',
     name: 'name',
     city: 'city'
}
```

This HTML Markup can give some info about what I want to do.

```
 <div ng-repeat="restaurant in restaurant | filter: ???">
        <div class="header">
            <h1 ng-bind="restaurant.city"></h1>
            <a>Select All</a>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix" ng-repeat="???">
            <input type="checkbox" id="restaurant.id" />
            <label ng-bind="restaurant.name"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Can I do it with one single array or do i need to create seperate city and restaurant arrays to do it?

Comment: Do you want to group your array of restaurants by city?

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I want to do =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to group restaurants by city, you can use groupBy of [**angular.filter**](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) module.

Just add the JS file from here: http://www.cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-filter to your project and use following code.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['angular.filter']);

function MyCtrl($scope) {    
    $scope.restaurants = [
       {id: 1, name: 'RestA', city: 'CityA'},
       {id: 2, name: 'RestB', city: 'CityA'},
       {id: 3, name: 'RestC', city: 'CityC'},
       {id: 4, name: 'RestD', city: 'CityD'}
    ];
}

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in restaurants | groupBy: 'city'">
        <b>{{ key }}</b>
      <li ng-repeat="restaurant in value">
          <i>restaurant: {{ restaurant.name }} </i>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've created [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7340/) for you with working example.

Comment: perfect. Works just as expected